# How to use result of FILE(GLOB_RECURSE) in EXECUTE_PROCESS?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am currently mentally broken by the CMake. Let me first show you what I am working on:

```
FILE( GLOB_RECURSE FLATBUFFER_SRC "*.fbs" )
STRING( REPLACE ";" " " FLATBUFFER_SRC_STR "${FLATBUFFER_SRC}" )

SET( FLATC_COMMAND "flatc --cpp --gen-mutable -o ${META_INSTALL_LOCATION} ${FLATBUFFER_SRC_STR}" )
MESSAGE( STATUS "${FLATC_COMMAND}" )

EXECUTE_PROCESS(
        COMMAND ${FLATC_COMMAND}
        RESULT_VARIABLE OUT
)

IF ( NOT ${OUT} EQUAL "0" )
    MESSAGE( STATUS "COMMAND EXIT WITH: ${OUT}" )
    MESSAGE( STATUS "META_INSTALL_LOCATION: ${META_INSTALL_LOCATION}" )
    MESSAGE( STATUS "FLATBUFFER_SRC_STR: ${FLATBUFFER_SRC_STR}" )
    MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "flatc has FAILED gracefully" )
ENDIF ()
```

And here is an output:

```sh
-- flatc --cpp --gen-mutable -o /home/black/Work/hubris/meta /home/black/Work/hubris/cmake-build-debug/META-prefix/src/META/fbs/game/base.fbs /home/black/Work/hubris/cmake-build-debug/META-prefix/src/META/fbs/game/util/vec.fbs
-- Configuring done
-- COMMAND EXIT WITH: No such file or directory
-- META_INSTALL_LOCATION: /home/black/Work/hubris/meta
-- FLATBUFFER_SRC_STR: /home/black/Work/hubris/cmake-build-debug/META-prefix/src/META/fbs/game/base.fbs /home/black/Work/hubris/cmake-build-debug/META-prefix/src/META/fbs/game/util/vec.fbs
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (MESSAGE):
  flatc has FAILED gracefully
```

While my question is "Why does it not work?" and it will stay the same, I am looking to understand ways of CMake. When I run in shell printed command:

```
flatc --cpp --gen-mutable -o /home/black/Work/hubris/meta /home/black/Work/hubris/cmake-build-debug/META-prefix/src/META/fbs/game/base.fbs /home/black/Work/hubris/cmake-build-debug/META-prefix/src/META/fbs/game/util/vec.fbs
```

It works like a dream. I am really confused and wasted a lot of time. 
Could anyone explain to me, what I have done **horrendously** wrong?

Comment: Do not quote **entire** value for `FLATC_COMMAND` variable. This is same as having quoted the whole command line in the shell: `"flatc --cpp --gen-mutable ..."` - the shell would interpret the whole string as a command name, and would fail with `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Hi!
While I do agree that the problem which you marked is similar, I personally think that it does not solve my problem. I do have seen that post, and It does not answer my... question? For some reason, when I did:
`EXECUTE_PROCESS( COMMAND flatc --cpp --gen-mutable -o ${META_INSTALL_LOCATION} ${FLATBUFFER_SRC_STR} )` It still does take the `${FLATBUFFER_SRC_STR}` as one arg... Could you maybe assist me with this? I can not grasp how to tell CMake to unpack this list as just args. Ahh, and flatc does understand that there is an single arg, which he cannot parse (this info might help). 
TY!

Comment: You obtain `FLATBUFFER_SRC` from `file(GLOB)`. Use this variable in `FLATC_COMMAND` variable's setting **without** any replacing (drop the `STRING( REPLACE)` line) and quoting: `SET( FLATC_COMMAND flatc --cpp --gen-mutable -o ${META_INSTALL_LOCATION} ${FLATBUFFER_SRC})`.

Comment: From you comment I understand the "core" problem, so I have updated the title to reflect it. While this "core" problem is very related to the duplicate question, I think it deserves the separate Question/Answer. I find no questions about the same (updated!) problem on Stack Overflow, so I have reopened the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result of `FILE(GLOB_RECURSE)` is a **list**, and exactly a *list* is expected by CMake when you specify arguments for a `COMMAND`. So, just pass this list to `execute_process`, without any modifications and *without quoting*:

```
FILE( GLOB_RECURSE FLATBUFFER_SRC "*.fbs" )

SET( FLATC_COMMAND flatc --cpp --gen-mutable -o ${META_INSTALL_LOCATION} ${FLATBUFFER_SRC} )

EXECUTE_PROCESS(
        COMMAND ${FLATC_COMMAND}
        RESULT_VARIABLE OUT
)
```

or, by removing intermediate `FLATC_COMMAND` variable:

```
FILE( GLOB_RECURSE FLATBUFFER_SRC "*.fbs" )

EXECUTE_PROCESS(
        COMMAND flatc --cpp --gen-mutable -o ${META_INSTALL_LOCATION} ${FLATBUFFER_SRC}
        RESULT_VARIABLE OUT
)
```

Comment: Pretty straight forward, I missed the fact of the list. I am really grateful for your help!